# How to retrieve object description using REST API/Object tooling/SOQL

Tags: soql, rest-api, custom-object, standard-objects, tooling-api

I got a question for retrieving custom/standard object description(marked in green color in below image) using rest/object tooling/soql.

[image: custom object description image]

As per Salesforce document (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) using EntityDefination we can fetch description of an custom object by forming soql query as below

```
https://infa8-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com//services/data/v53.0/query/?q=Select+Label+,+Description+,+QualifiedApiName+from+EntityDefinition+LIMIT+2
```

When it fire it throws below error saying Description filed in not present in the EntityDefination

```
[{"message":"\nSelect Label , Description , QualifiedApiName from\n               ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:16\nNo such column 'Description' on entity 'EntityDefinition'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]
```

Could someone please help on this .

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Tooling Api, so the endpoint is `/services/data/v53.0/tooling/query/`, while you used `/services/data/v53.0/query/`.

```
/services/data/v53.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Description+FROM+EntityDefinition+WHERE+DeveloperName='customtest'
```

Keep in mind that the DeveloperName is case sensitive, so `WHERE+DeveloperName='Account'` is correct, while `WHERE+DeveloperName='account'` returns no record.

If you need to query only description of custom object you could use [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customobject.htm) entity

```
/services/data/v53.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Description+FROM+CustomObject+WHERE+DeveloperName='NAME_OF_THE_OBJECT'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping.
This is what exactly i was looking for.

Comment: @infasalesforcetest You're welcome. Glad it helped